# SQLite 1.0.94 does not appear on EDM Providers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I noticed that this was an issue with 1.0.93, too, but it seems to also apply to 1.0.94.

More specifically:

1. Machine runs Windows 8.1 x64, Visual Studio 2013
2. Install sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.94.0 from official SQLite website
3. Create a C# .NET 4.5.1 Console Project
4. Add NuGet SQLite x86/x64
5. Add an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" to my project
6. Choose EF Designer from Database
7. **SQLite is not listed under Data Source Providers.**

On the contrary, SQLite provider appears if I add the connection under Server Explorer. This is not enough, however, as I need to use Entity Framework 6.1.1.

If anyone has a solution to this, please share it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you run Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.EF6 ?

Comment: @ErikEJ Yup, I have but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Show us your app.config, pls

Comment: @ErikEJ `<DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>`

Comment: @ErikEJ `<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>`

Comment: I think these are the sections of the app.config that matter.

Comment: I wish you had added them to your question so they were readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your system.data section looks like this:

```
<system.data>
 <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
 </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. However, I found that I get an error when updating the db "Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config."

Comment: This is fixed if I re-add the line <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
     
So it works, as long as I remove the above line when I need to add the connection, and then add it when I need to work with the database.