# SQLite connection not appearing for VS2015

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I have a similar problem with what is posted here:

[SQLite connection not appearing in Entity Data Model Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289701/sqlite-connection-not-appearing-in-entity-data-model-wizard)

Except that I use `VS2015` and I cannot even see the connection for `SQLite` in my Server Explorer:

[image]

I already install `System.Data.SQLite` from nuget and using  Entity Framework 6.1.3 and this setup:

```
sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.102.0
```

which is available in: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

But the option just doesn't appear.

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870045/sqlite-1-0-94-does-not-appear-on-edm-providers?rq=1) as well, it might help you

Comment: @kesh thanks for the comment. I have checked that post as well, the config file is just like that, but still it doesn't help. :( any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the bundle setup used, it is the bundle setup for VS2015 **for Windows 64-bit**. While the bundle setup capable of adding the Designer components in the VS2015 is ***only*** the bundle setup for VS2015 **for Windows 32-bit**.

> Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.6)
>
> This setup package features the mixed-mode assembly and will install
>   all the necessary runtime components and dependencies for the x86
>   version of the System.Data.SQLite 1.0.102.0 (3.13.0) package. The
>   Visual C++ 2015 Update 2 runtime for x86 is included. The .NET
>   Framework 4.6 is required.  This is the only setup package that is
>   capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio
>   2015.

In other words:

sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-**x86**-2015-1.0.102.0

instead of

sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-**x64**-2015-1.0.102.0

When I use the **x86** bundle, it is OK:

[image]